# Virtualbox: How to use VBoxBalloonCtrl

Tags: virtualbox, memory

I am running some virtual machines with Oracle Virtualbox 4.3.10, and they have guest additions installed. I know that you can manually balloon (take away unused memory from the guest) RAM with

```
VBoxManage controlvm "[VM name]" guestmemoryballoon [amount in MB]
```

I heard there is a way to automatically do the ballooning with VBoxBalloonCtrl.exe. But what are the command-line options for it, and what does each one do? The official documentation is not clear.

Comment: Have you read [this section](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#vboxwatchdog) of the documentation?

Comment: Oh, I see the arguments now. Problem solved.

Comment: If there is an answer that might be helpful to someone else, please create an answer and share, otherwise you should be able to delete your question.

Comment: No, I just misread the documentation at first.